# Nesting margin to achieve centered content

Tags: html, css, margin

I am running into an issue of trying to center children div while keeping the content aligned left. I have four boxes that are inline, the boxes are set to 25% width and are naturally aligned left. My issue is the four boxes does not look like they are centered on the page because of the natural alignment within the boxes. You can see this in the first image.

So what I thought to do was inside of my `.contact-connect-box` was to make a child div( `connect-box-wrap` ), somewhat as a wrap for inside of the box and add `margin: 0 auto;` , however this is not helping at all.

If you look at the second image, that is what I am after. I want the content to still be aligned left, but the margin for everything to be shifted over so that the box positioning appears centered on the page.

[image]

```
 #contact-connect {
          width: 80%;
          height: auto;
          margin: 0 10%;
          padding: 80px 0;
      }
      #contact-connect-box-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: auto;
        /*display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;*/

      }
       .contact-connect-box {
          width: 25%;
          margin: 60px 0 0 0;
          display: inline-block;
          /*border: 1px solid black;*/
          vertical-align: top;
          opacity: 0;
          transition:1s; -webkit-transition:1s;
      }
      .connect-box-wrap {
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

<div id="contact-connect">
        <div id="contact-connect-box-container">
            <div class="contact-connect-box">
                <div class="connect-box-wrap">
                <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Call</h2>
                <div class="contact-connect-description">gfdgg</div>
                </div>
            </div><div class="contact-connect-box">
            <div class="contact-connect-box">
                <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Write</h2>
                <div class="contact-connect-description">
                    Reach out to us
                    <br>
                    <div id="scroll" class="contact-connect-link">Fill out our contact form.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><div class="contact-connect-box">
            <div class="contact-connect-box">
                <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Visit</h2>
                <div class="contact-connect-description">
                    gsdfg
                </div>
                </div>
            </div><div class="contact-connect-box">
            <div class="contact-connect-box">
                <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Connect</h2>
                <div class="contact-connect-description">
                    <div class="contact-connect-link"><a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">Visit us on Facebook</a></div>
                    <div class="contact-connect-link"><a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank">See us on Youtube</a></div>
                    <div class="contact-connect-link"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would **scrap the .content-connect-box-container** because you already have the .content-connect-box so that seems redundant. I did this by **centre text aligning .content-connect-box** and then **left text aligning .connect-box-wrap**.  Also be careful about how you choose to make your spacing. If you're working in % make sure to stick with that, if you mix % with px, certain screen sizes will break your layout. Feel free to play around with different margin %s in my code to see how I spaced everything.

```
    <div id="contact-connect">

        <div class="contact-connect-box">
            <div class="connect-box-wrap">
            <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Call</h2>
                <div class="contact-connect-description">gfdgg hgakhglkrjhg kjshfglkjshd flkjgshfd oweir werowheor weriwjeroija 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contact-connect-box">
            <div class="connect-box-wrap">
            <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Call</h2>
                <div class="contact-connect-description">gfdgg
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="contact-connect-box">
            <div class="connect-box-wrap">
            <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Call</h2>
                <div class="contact-connect-description">gfdgg
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="contact-connect-box">
            <div class="connect-box-wrap">
            <h2 class="contact-connect-title">Call</h2>
                <div class="contact-connect-description">gfdggaksj 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 </div>

<style type="text/css">

#contact-connect {
      width: 80%;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 10%;
      padding: 80px 0;
      display: block;
  }


   .contact-connect-box {
      width: 21%;
      margin: 0 0 0 1%;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 2px solid black;
      vertical-align: top;
      text-align: center;

  }


  .connect-box-wrap {
    margin: 10% auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;

  }



  </style>
```